# *nix convention for storing user logs?

Tags: linux, unix, logging

What’s a conventional log location for processes that run on behalf of users?

- `~/.foo/logs/` — my top choice but not super awesome
- `/var/log/foo.uid/` — Non-system users can’t create directories here, needs cooperation to create in the first place.
- A common file in `/var/log/` (e.g. `/var/log/foo.log`) — Not private
- etc.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest going for `/var/log/foo.uid/`, because `/var/log/` is my first go-to place when searching for logs on a server.

Another option is to use your first choice, `~/.foo/logs/`, and create a symlink to it under `/var/log`.

Comment: I did actually mean user ID, not PID (i.e. more than one user may be running a program at the same time and they all need their own log locations).

Comment: Oh! My mistake, it's still a bit too early a monday morning. Then it makes sense to add the `uid` or username.

Answer (score 3):

While `/var/log` is the canonical place to look for logs, as @pkhamre points out, I do not see the need to pollute the folder with "user"-generated logs. I would prefer only system-wide services to log to `/var/log`.

That said, if the app is a GUI app (running in X), I would suggest following the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and drop the logs into `$XDG_DATA_HOME/foo/log/` with `$XDG_DATA_HOME` defaulting to `$HOME/.local/share`. This has one drawback, though. You need to work harder if you want to aggregate the logs for some reason -- with the previous solution a `cat /var/log/foo.*/*` would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

As `/var/log` is non writable by users and if you don't want to keep the logs under their respective home directories, I would suggest using `/var/tmp/foo.logs.uid` which would be both writable by users and centralized.